# Using double iterators to refer the list in the map

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, iterator

I tried to use the struct like map. When I tried to use iterator to refer the list element, something wrong happened.
The code is followed.

```
map<string,list<string>> node;
void ContructGraph(vector<string>& wordList){
    for(int i=0;i<wordList.size();i++){
        list<string> *tem=new list<string>();
        tem->push_back(wordList[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<wordList.size();j++){
            if(CheckDifference(wordList[i],wordList[j]))tem->push_back(wordList[j]);
        }
        node.insert(std::pair<string,list<string>>(wordList[i],*tem));

    }
    for(int i=0;i<wordList.size();i++){
        visited.insert(std::pair<string,bool>(wordList[i],false));
        nodeLength.insert(std::pair<string,int>(wordList[i],0));

    }
    for(map<string,list<string>>::const_iterator it=node.begin();it!=node.end();++it){
        cout<<"node "<<it->first<<endl;
        list<string> newList=it->second;// no error
        std::list<string>::iterator newIterator =(newList).begin();//no error
        std::list<string>::iterator newnewIterator=(it->second).begin();// with error
        /*
        for(std::list<string>:: const_iterator s_it=it->second.begin();s_it!=it->second.end()+s_it){
            cout<<*s_it<<" ";
        }
        */
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

the error message is

```
conversion from 'std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}' requested
```

For my understanding, the iterator is something like pointer points to the element. it->second should represent the list in the map. If I assign the list to a list object, it just worked fine. Why it did not work when I used "it->second.begin()"? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`it` is a `const_iterator`.  `it->second` is therefore `const`, and `(it->second).begin()` is also a `const_iterator`.  So `newnewIterator` needs to be `std::list<string>::const_iterator`.  Or just use `auto newnewIterator` if your compiler is new enough to support it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to iterator for it->second which is constant.
Try to replace

```
for(map<string,list<string>>::const_iterator it=node.begin();it!=node.end();++it){
```

with

```
for(map<string,list<string>>::iterator it=node.begin();it!=node.end();++it){
```

This should work.

Comment: as ~1201ProgramAlarm pointed out use auto wherever necessary.